# Media Query Not Working display:none to display:inline

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a simple html as follows

```
<div id="break" style="display:none">
 <br />
</div>
```

I am trying to display that break when user decreases the window size. I am using css3 media query. I tried as follows

```
@media only screen and (max-height :510px){

    #break
    {
        display:inline;
    }
}
```

But that Break is not showing up. Anything am I missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're applying the display:none; styling through inline HTML (style="display:none"). By default, CSS does not override the inline styling. In order to have the CSS override the inline styling, use the !important; declaration:

```
@media only screen and (max-height :510px) {
    #break
    {
        display:inline !important;
    }
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MarkvA/kEuHe/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can start with putting display none into the external style sheet instead of inline, where it will override your CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the specificity of the `style` attribute. Here's a sentence from the CSS2 specification (and more specific: the [specificity section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)):

> The declaration in the "style" attribute will override the one in the STYLE element because of cascading rule 3, since it has a higher specificity.

Don't get confused by the term `STYLE element`, this also covers CSS rules from external stylesheets.

So apart from this being a slightly weird way of displaying a line break you'd just have to put the `display: none;` line into your CSS file or `<style>` element.

```
#break
{
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 510px){

    #break
    {
        display: inline;
    }
}
```